# MobX stores updating 'delayed'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, store, mobx

I have a simple tab menu, and an overview: Within the overview, I'm reaching for a store, a MobX store, and I'm fetching what tab I'm currently in, then displaying in as a text to see what tab I've selected, problem is that the text update is 'delayed';

Say the current selected tab is 'A', if I click on 'B', the text will still display 'A', however, if I click on 'C', it'll display 'B' (so the tab that was selected before), and it goes on for ever;

I haven't tried much, looked up a bunch of tutorials for MobX but none were relevant, at least not for my case. No compiling error, everything is imported/hooked as it should be (I think).

Here's a little scheme: [image: SCHEME]

For the code part I'm just gonna paste the relevant code so you don't have to read it all:

Click event occurs here:

`<MenuItem title="Dashboard" icon="home" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)} active={this.state.selected === "Dashboard"}/>`

It's handled via:

```
handleClick(event)
{
    let txt = event.target.innerText        

    if(txt === this.state.selected)
        return;

    this.setState({
        selected: txt
    })

    UserStore.tab = this.state.selected
}
```

And so the menu actually can fetch and remain updated store-wise:

`import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
export default observer(Menu)`

Here's the full UserStore.js class:

```
import { extendObservable } from 'mobx';

class UserStore {
    constructor() {
        extendObservable(this, {
            loading: true,
            isLoggedIn: false,
            username: "",
            tab: "",
            theme: "Dark"
        })
    }
}

export default new UserStore();
```

And at last, the selected tab display:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            Currently in tab: {UserStore.tab}               
        )
    }
}

import { observer } from 'mobx-react'    
export default observer(Main)
```

I do understand that this issue might seem trivial (or not?) but it's only been two days since I've started so, here I am.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick(event)
{
    let txt = event.target.innerText        

    if(txt === this.state.selected)
        return;

    this.setState({
        selected: txt
    })

    UserStore.tab = this.state.selected
}
```

This was wrong: UserStore.tab = this.state.selected

This is ok though: UserStore.tab = txt